# default date() should be 3 months ahead

Tags: php

My server has many application instances.

I came across a problem that one of my application instance needs to be tested with the future date. i.e I want to test the application as it is running in 2013.

If i change the system date then it will work fine but the other instances will also get effected.

I want the future date for only one instance and the rest should work as it is.

i.e if i use date('Y-m-d'); it should jump for 3 months and display the future date.

and i dont want to add seconds to the default date as that might be a huge change in my application.

Comment: my question is,  if i echo date('Y-m-d') i need the date 3 months ahead from now. and i dont want to change my server date as it will impact other applications.

Comment: You can look in [override_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) from manuals.

Answer (score 3):

And that's why you write your application in a way that is *testable*.

Not good:

```
function doSomething() {
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    ...
}
```

Good:

```
function doSomething($ts = null) {
    if (!$ts) {
        $ts = time();
    }
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $ts);
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1. all the other answers (including mine) are suggesting ways to add three months to date, but this is the only one that truly understands the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can make your own date function. It would serve as a hook to all date usage.

```
function mydate($format) {
    $jump = ' +3 months';
    return date($format, strtotime(date($format) . $jump));
}
```

you can than change all occurrences of `date` to `mydate`. If you decide to switch back to present, just leave `$jump = ''`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
date('Y-m-d', time() + 3 * 30 * 24 * 3600);
```

Comment: months are not all 30 days long, you know.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the PHP5 DateTime classes. They're a bit more wordy, but much more powerful than the old-style PHP date handling functions.

```
$dateNow = new DateTime();
$dateAhead = $dateNow->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('3 months'));

print $dateAhead->format('Y-m-d');
```